# Query MySQL Datetime Field For Any Records Made 11 Months Ago

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select

Essentially, I have an `orders` table and each day I'm running a cronjob to check the logs and see which customers ordered 11 months ago, because I need to warn them that their warranty expires in 1 month. What's the best way this query is accomplished?

I could do it a few ways, but I'm interested in seeing opinions of the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE order_date = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 11 MONTH
;
```

This will find all rows with order_date value exactly 11 months old.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`date_add`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) with a month `interval` and compare it to `now()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   orders
WHERE  DATE_ADD (order_date, INTERVAL 11 MONTH) <= NOW()
```

Comment: I'd recommend staying away from function calls on fields in WHERE clauses if possible; it eliminates any performance benefits of indexes. Of course, if there are no indexes, it won't "hurt"; but would need rewritten to take advantage of them if indexes were added later.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE order_date = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH))
```

I have added UNIX_TIMESTAMP as MySQL stores date in UNIX timestamps

Comment: It may store them internally as such, but comparisons don't work that way. Ex: `CURDATE() = unix_timestamp(curdate())` is false. Even if it did work, that seems a bit pointless since you would expect `DATE_SUB()` to already return a value comparable to a date field.